# MySQL 8.0.16: Select Date LIKE query fails

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, mariadb

I have 3 MySQL/MariaDB servers running for application development and testing:

- `MySQL Community Server 5.7.32`
- `MySQL Community Server 8.0.16`
- `MariaDB Community Server 10.4.12`

The servers are configured to run on different ports on the same machine.

`SELECT @@sql_mode` for all servers:

- `MySQL Community Server 5.7.32`: `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`
- `MySQL Community Server 8.0.16`: `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`
- `MariaDB Community Server 10.4.12`: `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

I stumbled across some SELECT queries in old code I maintain whose fails to run, for e.g. searching a date with a given pattern. The queries look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `userTable` WHERE `birthDate` LIKE '2020-%-%';
SELECT * FROM `userTable` WHERE `birthDate` LIKE '%12%';
```

The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userTable` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` TEXT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
   `birthDate` DATE,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When I run the queries on `MySQL Community Server 8.0.16` they fail with the error `Error Code: 1525. Incorrect DATE value: '2020-%-%'.` and `Error Code: 1525. Incorrect DATE value: '%12%'.`.

`MySQL Community Server 5.7.32` and `MariaDB Community Server 10.4.12` executes the queries successfully.

Why does `MySQL Community Server 8.0.16` fails to execute these SELECT queries?

PS: The first SELECT query can be written as

```
SELECT * FROM `userTable` WHERE YEAR(`birthDate`) = 2020;
```

to run on all 3 servers.

EDIT: It's a bug in `MySQL Community Server 8.0.16` and fixed in version `8.0.22`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f145c1213da3422bda7dd5b78d4cb808 Add your source data and reproduce the issue.

Comment: *Why does MySQL Community Server 8.0.16 fails to execute these SELECT queries?* Show `SELECT @@sql_mode;` output for all servers. `NO_ZERO_DATE` and `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` may be a reason.

Comment: Akina I added it to the question

Comment: *added it* The modes are not default, so *Except this none of the configurations are changed.* is not true. PS. Have you found the rows which' values causes an issue? does they produces the same error on the fiddle?

Comment: It's an error in the queries, not in the data

Comment: `LIKE` is for strings, not for date values. Regardless if some MySQL versions actually accept this, you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: *It's an error in the queries, not in the data* If so this is version-specific issue - fiddle shows that the queries itself are correct (my 8.0.18 and 8.0.21 shows queries correctness). Have you checked this issue on some literal data, like ```SELECT * FROM (SELECT '2020-01-01' AS `birthDate`) AS `userTable` WHERE `birthDate` LIKE '2020-%-%';```?

Comment: It runs fine with the literal data

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I know myself it's a bad query. It's not my code, this thing is over 8 years old (and the guy who wrote it is long gone)

Comment: It's a bug in MySQL Community Server 8.0.16, MySQL Community Server 8.0.22 runs fine with it. -.-

Comment: File a bug at bugs.mysql.com an post a link to it here.

Answer (score 2):

You should be comparing a bona fide date column against valid date literals, *not* strings, e.g. to find records in 2020:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM userTable
WHERE birthDate >= '2020-01-01' AND birthDate < '2021-01-01';  -- sargable :-)
```

Or maybe:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM userTable
WHERE YEAR(birthDate) = 2020;  -- not sargable though :-(
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, it doesn't explain why the queries doesn't run on the newer MySQL server

Comment: It has to do with a change in the casting rules, but don't even go down that road.  I mean, regardless of the explanation, it isn't going to change the situation.

Comment: Especially with the 2nd query the application should to be able to search all entries where the date contains "12", giving results like 1912-05-15, 2020-12-03 and 2020-05-12 and so on

Comment: If you really want to do that (bad idea), then first use `DATE_FORMAT` on the date column, and then compare it against a `LIKE` expression.  Do not directly compare the date (and, better yet, use my answer).

Comment: @fireandfuel . . . This is the correct way to write the code.  Converting dates to strings is a bad idea from a performance perspective.  Relying on implicit formats just makes your code vulnerable to bugs as well as incurring performance issues and making it unnecessarily hard to understand.